# IOS youtube player shows white screen while loading

Tags: ios, video, youtube, cocoapods

I am integrating youtube player via cocoapods. I am using storyboard, problem is while loading video, youtube player shows blank white space it gives very ugly look to my complete UI. How can I show some sort of loader while it is loading.

I have also tried to use activity indicator behind the player but I guess player view itself has white color which hides my indicator. Also, I tried to use indicator on the player but it kept on showing even if video got load.

And I didn't find any possible solution in delegate by which I can find that weather the video loads or not?

Any possible solution Please????? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I had same issue so I made my view's color black and an imageview over it. Then I fetched the you tube cover image for that imageView.

Comment: thanks for mentioning but can you please explain a little more ?

Comment: Are you using XCDYouTubeKit ? And how you are showing youtube view ? And when you want to play video ?

Comment: I just drag drop a view and changed the class of view by YTPlayerView

Comment: Make that view's background color black. Take a ImageView there and you can shoe youtube video's coverpage there. And one button over, in that button's click action play youtube video.

Answer (score 0):

You can take an imageview on top of your player and set the background to black and in player delegate when player state become ready , set the image background color to clear.

Hope this will work, this works for me.